# star wildcard in bash

Tags: linux, bash, wildcard

I've got a small problem with my bash script. I try to change file name in current directory for whole files with `txt` extension to `text` extension. For exampel `1.txt` to `1.text`

My script looks like this now:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=`ls /home/name/*.txt`
NAME=*.txt
RENAME=*.text

for file in FILES
do 
mv $NAME $RENAME
done
```

i try whole combination with single, double quotes and backticks and I receive errors all the time.

Do you have some ideas how to receive wildcards "*" in bash?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you forgot to run `shellcheck` on your code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not at all how you do that.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

OLD=.txt
NEW=.text
FILES=(/home/name/*"$OLD")    

for file in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  mv "$file" "${file%$OLD}$NEW}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your script. Firstly, you shouldn't run `ls` and attempt to store its output like that. If you want to iterate through those file, just do it in the loop:

```
for file in /home/name/*.txt
```

Now the shell is doing all the work for you, and as a bonus handling any kind of weird filenames that you might have.

In your example you were looping over the literal string "FILES", not the variable, but I guess that was just a typo.

The built-in way to change the filename is to use a parameter expansion to remove the old one, then concatenate with the new one:

```
old=txt
new=text

for file in /home/name/*"$old"
do
    mv "$file" "${file%$old}$new"
done
```

If it is possible that there are no files matching the glob, then by default, the `/home/name/*.txt` will not be expanded and your loop will just run once. then you have a couple of options:

- use `shopt -s nullglob` so that `/home/name/*.txt` expands to null, and the loop is skipped
- add an explicit check inside the loop to ensure that `$file` exists before trying to `mv`:

  ```
  for file in /home/name/*"$old"
  do
      [ -e "$file" ] || continue
      mv "$file" "${file%$old}$new"
  done
  ```

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use rename to rename filenames.

   ```
   rename .txt .text /home/name/*.txt
   ```
2. And if you want to do this by looping, you can

   ```
   for FILE in /data/tmp/*.txt; do
       mv  "${FILE}" "${FILE/.txt/.text}"
   done
   ```

Comment: I've added the important quoting you omitted.  You still have the issue that the parameter substitution will replace the *first* `.txt` in the name, rather than the last.